# Foursquare tips limit

Tags: json, foursquare

I'm using API Foursquare to get tips about some companies. 
So I have this request link:

```
linkTips = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID/tips?limit=10&sort=recent&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&v=XXXXXXX"
```

limit = 10.

And it works, if count of tips more than 100.
But if count of tips less than 100 I'm getting all of them.
How can I fix it? I don't need all of 65 tips. I need just 10 recent tips.

Comment: I was able to replicate this and seems like a bug - I'll let you know when this gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing everything correctly, it's a bug on our (Foursquare) side.

[Update]: It's fixed now

Comment: Now I can't paginate through the tips. `offset` doesn't seem to do anything. Example: https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4ac518e7f964a52070ab20e3/tips?v=20150101&sort=recent&oauth_token=XXXX&limit=10&offset=10 and https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4ac518e7f964a52070ab20e3/tips?v=20150101&sort=recent&oauth_token=XXXX&limit=10&offset=20 return the same tips.

Comment: I've created a new question for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698973/foursquare-api-cannot-paginate-venues-venue-id-tips-offset-not-working